# Running shell command from Gradle script

Tags: shell, gradle

I am having the darndest time trying to figure out how to run a shell command from Gradle, since it seems like Gradle makes it very difficult to do this.

Here is the command:

```
git branch --merged | grep -v \* | grep -v master | grep -v develop | grep -v dmz | xargs git branch -D
```

It's just a convenience command to clean up local branches that have been merged.

Here is the task I created:

```
task gitCleanLocalBranches {
    doLast {
        exec {
            workingDir '.'
            commandLine 'git branch --merged | grep -v \\* | grep -v master | grep -v develop | grep -v dmz | xargs git branch -D'

        }
    }
}
```

The task fails with:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':gitCleanLocalBranches'.
> A problem occurred starting process 'command 'git branch -a''

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':gitCleanLocalBranches'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
        ...
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: A problem occurred starting process 'command 'git branch --merged | grep -v \* | grep -v master | grep -v develop | grep -v dmz | xargs git branch -D''
        at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.execExceptionFor(DefaultExecHandle.java:222)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: net.rubygrapefruit.platform.NativeException: Could not start 'git branch --merged | grep -v \* | grep -v master | grep -v develop | grep -v dmz | xargs git branch -D'
        at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.DefaultProcessLauncher.start(DefaultProcessLauncher.java:27)
        ... 4 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "git branch --merged | grep -v \* | grep -v master | grep -v develop | grep -v dmz | xargs git branch -D" (in directory "/home/wlaw/sterlib"): error=2, No such file or directory
        at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.DefaultProcessLauncher.start(DefaultProcessLauncher.java:25)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
        ... 7 more
```

So I figured that the command is too complicated so I tried something simpler, and changed `commandLine` to:

```
commandLine 'git branch -a'
```

But I got the exact same error. Why is Gradle not able to find anything in the `PATH` environment variable?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The command to execute and its arguments must be separate parameters to pass to `commandLine`, like this:

```
commandLine 'git', 'branch', '-a'
```

If you want to execute a complicated pipeline as in your first example,
you can wrap it in a shell script.

I cannot test this, but I think this should work as well:

```
commandLine 'sh', '-c', 'git branch --merged | grep -v -e \* -e master -e develop -e dmz | xargs git branch -D'
```

Note: I took the liberty and simplified the `grep` a bit.

Lastly, you could also create a Git alias in your `.gitconfig` to wrap the complex pipeline.

Comment: To your first point, that certainly is annoying and so seemingly unnecessarily complicated, especially for single commands with many arguments. But to your second point, that was sort of hoping something I wouldn't have to do, since this is really just a one liner, making a whole new file seems to sidestep Gradle's issue with not being able to just run a shell command from within build.gradle.

Comment: re: just run a shell command. In Unix, pipes are used to separate multiple commands. You can call it a one-liner if you like, but it still represents multiple commands.

Comment: @wheeler I added two more alternatives to my answer that might be suitable for you.

Answer (score 10):

If you need to save the command output you could do this:

```
def gitBranchA = "git branch -a".execute().text.trim()
```

Comment: Why did this work so well and `commandLine` didn't?