# Android - Run a Java method in Gradle after an apk build

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm currently building a Android application, and I would like to do some processing after the apk is built.

I've already succeeded to launch a gradle task after the build:

```
tasks.whenTaskAdded {
        task ->
            if(task.name == 'assembleRelease'){
                task.finalizedBy postApkProcess
            }
    }

    task postApkProcess{
        doLast {
           println 'OK'
        }
    }
```

But I struggle to launch a method inside that task. What I would like to do is to call something like `new MyClass().postBuild()` inside the class (or if it is not possible, run the main method of a Java class), but I don't find a way to do it.

I've tried to build a task `task postProcess(type: JavaExec)`, but the line `apply plugin: 'java'`conflicts with the Android plugin.

Is there a way to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [commandLine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46959783/running-shell-command-from-gradle-script) to run the main method in MyClass which could call postBuild:

```
commandLine 'java' '<pathToSrc>/<mypackage>.MyClass'
```

Be careful to set the package name and source location properly. The path should point to the location (minus package directory tree) of the MyClass.class file, **not MyClass.java**. If your class is not compiled or it changes often, you could call javac to compile it each time before you run it (optionally using a shell script / batch file) to bundle both commands and simplify the gradle call and help you test the setup directly.

If your class uses code from libraries ensure you add them to the classpath:

```
'-classpath' 'mylib1.jar:mylib2.jar'
```

If you use java in the build process you might also have a look at [scar](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/scar)